# Ajax call always returns error even on successful call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get the hang of Ajax calls and I'm struggling with a basic peace of code :)

I keep getting the error alert even when the call seems to be successful.
I tried to debug the code and added some breakpoints and noticed that done-function does execute.
The form-info has been written away and a string is returned from the php-script.
For a brief while the text does appear but then disapears after the done-function.
While debugging i don't get the error message. It only appears while running the script normally.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div id="formDiv">
<form method="post" id="form">
<label for="title">Title: </label>
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" />
<label for="composer">Composer: </label>
<input type="text" name="composer" id="composer" />
<label for="link">Link: </label>
<input type="text" name="link" id="link" />
<label for="description">Description: </label>
<input type="text" name="description" id="description" />
<input type="submit">
</div>

<div id="outerDiv">
    <p id="p"></p>
</div>

<script>
$("#form").submit(function(){
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: postData,
    dataType: "text"    
    })
    .done(function(data){
        $("#p").text(data);
    })
    .fail(function(){
        alert("Error!");
    });
    });

</script>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php   
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db');
if ($dbc->connect_error) {
die('Connect Error: ' . $dbc->connect_error);
}

$title = $_POST['title'];
$composer = $_POST['composer'];
$link = $_POST['link'];
$description= $_POST['description'];

$query = "INSERT INTO table(Titel, Componist, Link, Description) VALUES ('$title', '$composer', '$link', '$description')";
mysqli_query($dbc, $query);


$resultquery = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM table");
$result = "";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultquery)){
    $result .= $row["Titel"]." | ".$row["Componist"]." | ".$row["Link"]." | ".$row["Description"]."\n";
}

echo $result;
mysqli_close($dbc);

?>
```

Comment: Have you observed the request / response process in the browser's console?

Comment: You are vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: SQL injection attacks: I know. I'm just trying out a simple function.

Comment: Request/response: Like it should be. The form data and a string with all the table elements as a response

Answer (score 1):

Instead of alerting you might try to use console.log.
You might also add parameters to the faile function to see what comes from the server

```
funcation fail( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
    console.log("textStatus: " + textStatus);
    console.log("errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
}
```

Comment: This gives me textStatus: error and errorThrown: blank :s

Comment: Then look at HTTP traffic. You can check it with developer tools in any modern browser or with extensions like Firebug for Firefox. Look specifically what is HTTP status code for the response.

Comment: Status says 200 OK. I've made a screenshot of the POST: http://i.imgur.com/G1oPm2W.png .

Answer (score 0):

I doubt whether you have written your field names and table name correctly

```
INSERT INTO db(Titel, Componist, Link, Description)
```

Spellings are wrong in title, and you are inserting data not into the table, you insert them into db. This is wrong. Add your table name

Comment: db could be the table name and titel may not be english. especially since these are repeated in the output

Comment: @Kai - I thought that he has mistakenly done it. Yes field names have been repeated in several places and could be some other language, but I thank you for clearing one point. i.e db could me the table name. Tks man

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. I changed some names while posting the question. It should be table indeed.

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot of different things this seems to work:

I've added the action attribute to my form tag

```
<form method="post" id="form" action="test.php">
```

And added preventDefault() on the form and changed the error handling

```
<script>
$("#form").submit(function(e){
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: postData,
    dataType: "text"    
    })
    .error(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { console.log(errorThrown); })
    .done(function(data){
        $("#p").text(data);
    })
    e.preventDefault();
    });

</script>
```

So why is the action attribute necessary for this to work?

Comment: It isn't necessary. False positive. Most likely one of the other changes fixed your issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following snippet using `success` and `error` callbacks rather than `done` and fail`.

```
$("#form").submit(function(){
    var postData = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: postData,
        dataType: "text", 
        success: function(data){
             $('#p').text(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Error!");
        }   
});
```

Comment: That was the first way I wrote it. Same result.

Comment: "**Deprecation Notice:** The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead." - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/